# Javascript for loop with .appendchild() is appending values of last object from [object object] inside html dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetDetails();
});

function GetDetails() {
    let albumlist = document.getElementById("album-list");



    $.ajax({
        url: '/Store/browseajax',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: '@ViewBag.genreid' },
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);


            for (x in data) {

                    let li = document.createElement("li");
                    console.log(li);
                    let a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.id = "refdetails";
                    a.href = "";


                    let img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.alt = "";
                    img.src = "";
                    img.id = "image";

                    let span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.id = "title";

                    a.appendChild(img);
                    a.appendChild(span);
                    li.appendChild(a);
                    albumlist.appendChild(li);

                    let url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Store")?id=' + data[x].albumid;

                    $('#refdetails').attr("href", url);
                    $('#image').attr("src", data[x].albumarturl);
                    $('#image').attr("alt", data[x].albumtitle);
                    $('#title').text(data[x].albumtitle);                   
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });


}
```

Please anyone explain me where i am doing it wrong. I want to display both objects inside my data, but instead it is showing only the last object values though it is running iterations appropriately.

[image]

this image show my console.log data

Comment: Use classes instead of ids. An id must be unique. When jQuery looks for an id like in `$('#refdetails')`, it retreive only the first only. not all... Use classes.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there and welcome to SO!

Let me try to gime some insights going through your code...

Here you are creating new DOM elements:

```
let li = document.createElement("li");
console.log(li);
let a = document.createElement("a");

a.id = "refdetails";
a.href = "";

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.alt = "";
img.src = "";
```

Now, note the following lines. You assing a unique id to the elements, in this case "**image**" and "**title**"

```
img.id = "image";

let span = document.createElement("span");
span.id = "title";

a.appendChild(img);
a.appendChild(span);
li.appendChild(a);
albumlist.appendChild(li);
```

And then, you try to assing some values to these elements:

```
$('#refdetails').attr("href", url);
$('#image').attr("src", data[x].albumarturl);
$('#image').attr("alt", data[x].albumtitle);
$('#title').text(data[x].albumtitle);
```

You are trying to append to the dom exactly the same elements (`#image` and `#title`) in each loop. **Elements should have an unique id, so if you try to insert a new node with the same id, the previous one will be removed prior to inserting the new one**.

If you want to see all the album titles in the DOM, you should append a new element to the DOM in each loop.

You can play with this idea:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){             
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.id = "title" + i;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `a.id` use `a.className` for your elements you created dynamically, see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/15yozn24/15/

You also need to append to the unique data, so the element will be `a.className = "refdetails" + data[x].id;` and the append will look like `$('.refdetails'+ data[x].id).attr("href", url);`

The issue is happening because you are trying to insert data into a ID and this will only work for the first ID found in the DOM since it's unqiue.

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    GetDetails();
});

function GetDetails() {
    let albumlist = document.getElementById("album-list");



    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
        type: 'GET',
        /* data: { id: '@ViewBag.genreid' }, */
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);


            for (x in data) {

                    let li = document.createElement("li");
                    /* console.log(li) */;
                    let a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.className = "refdetails" + data[x].id;
                    a.href = "";


                    let img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.alt = "";
                    img.src = "";
                    img.className = "image" + data[x].id;

                    let span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.className = "title" + data[x].id;

                    a.appendChild(img);
                    a.appendChild(span);
                    li.appendChild(a);
                    albumlist.appendChild(li);

                    let url = 'http://yourwebsite.com/?id=' + data[x].id;

                    $('.refdetails'+ data[x].id).attr("href", url);
                    $('.image' + data[x].id).attr("src", 'https://via.placeholder.com/150');
                    $('.image' + data[x].id).attr("alt", data[x].title);
                    $('.title' + data[x].id).text(data[x].title);                   
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: `$('.refdetails')`  this selector will point to all element of list (including previous rendered by loop). Last element overwrite to all :(

Comment: Thanks @Sachink totally missed that. I've updated it to pass unique ID from the json.